# Cast to a generic class type in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My objective is to return the fetched results from the DB to any given type (model). For some reason I'm getting the error as "Use of undeclared type 'model'". What am I missing here ? and how to achieve my objective.

```
func fetchData<T>(entity:String, model: T)-> T? {


    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:entity)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {

            let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0 {

                return result as model // Point that gets the error 

            }

        } catch {

          print("Failed to retrive data")
        }

    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to cast.

Based on Joakim's answer I recommend to make the method more generic and also `throw` to hand over the error to the caller.

Creating the fetch request with the generic type gets rid of the type cast

```
func fetchData<T : NSFetchRequestResult>(entity:String, model: T.Type) throws -> [T] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName:entity)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    return try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
}
```

And use it

```
do {
    let result = try fetchData(entity: “Foo”, model: Foo.self) 
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("Failed to retrive data")
}
```

Comment: This seems more generic and wonderful, but then I see the error is also a generic type. Thus, in case it Failed to retrieve data where do i catch it ?

Comment: You wrap the call of `fetchData` in the `do - catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `as` and not `is` when casting and the type to cast to is `T` not `model`, or rather it is `[T]` since it is an array so the function declaration needs to be modified as well

```
func fetchDsata<T>(entity:String, model: T.Type)-> [T]? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:entity)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0 {
                return result as? [T]
            }
        } catch {
          print("Failed to retrive data")
        }
    return nil
}
```